# quicksort (n arrays should be treated as 1 and values remapped as needed)

Tags: c++, c

I have a linked list of arrays (struct at bottom of post)

Each array may have values like the below example

```
Array1[] = {6,36,8,23};
Array2[] = {8,23,5,73};
Array3[] = {2,5,1,9};
```

I need to sort these so that all 3 arrays are treated as 1 large array...

I need to use quicksort so that it uses in-place processing... I am working with very large arrays and cannot afford to use additional memory..

The result should be something like this

```
Array1[] = {1,2,5,5};
Array2[] = {6,8,8,9};
Array3[] = {23,23,36,73};
```

Currently i am only able to sort each array individually... but thats not exactly what i need :(

```
struct iSection {
    unsigned long     Section_Count; // Total # of points in this block of memory

    int              *Section_Arr;   // Point cloud for current block of memory
    struct iSection  *Next;          // Pointer to next section
} iSection;


struct iDatabase {
    struct iSection     *First_Section;
    struct iSection     *Last_Section;
} iDatabase;
```

Comment: @all waiting for maestros to answer this wonderful question.

Comment: @Steve: In your example all the arrays have the same number of elements. Is that always the case? Also, why do you need to use quicksort?

Comment: Any in-place sorting algorithm that is efficient would be fine. Quicksort is just what i am using now.

Comment: @Steve: are all the sub-arrays of the same size or could they differ in size? If they're all the same size, it should be trivial to write an array wrapper that overrides the [] operator to remap the indices. If the sizes of the small arrays are all different, then you will need another array to keep track of their running sum and do a binary search to find which array to remap the indices.

Comment: Tagged C and C++, looks like C. Would a C++ answer be acceptable?

Comment: Is your linked list big? if not, you can create an array that contains all your nodes (iSection) and the size of all arrays to this section. Using this array you get O(1) access time to any element in your collection, and by defining an iterator for it can simply use quicksort and get O(nlogn) average as usual.
If this works and you have troubles with the technical part (Defining the iterator for std::sort) I can clarify that part as well.

Comment: the linked list and the arrays are very large... the arrays can be different sizes... The size of the array is stored in section_count

Comment: I strongly suggest you **DO NOT** try to use a multi-language solution. Single-language solutions will be both easier to understand/modify and more perfomant (because they can use specifics for each language)

Comment: @Steve: Is there a particular reason why you are not using `std::vector` and/or `std::list`?

Comment: @Shiroko: how is it possible to lookup the auxiliary array in O(1)? The fastest way to lookup the auxiliary array that I can think of is to use binary search in O(log(n)).

Comment: Depending on how many elements you have vs how many groups, and whether you're willing to temporarily allocate more memory or not (and how much) it may be better to do something else, e.g. quicksort each list in isolation and then merge the lists back together. The accepted answer will work but will produce horrible performance in certain cases, e.g. a million sections of one element each.

Comment: @Lie Ryan: I think O(log(n)) is indeed required too, even using Fenwick Trees / B+ Trees.

Comment: Heapsort is another in-place algorithm, unlike Quicksort it guarantees O(n log n) time in the worst case.  There are also in-place variants of Mergesort, but they are rather complicated, so I'd avoid them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not that hard, more an interfacing issue then an algorithmics issue.

Write a wrapper container that provides an interface for accessing members and writing (say `operator[]` in C++) and internally it maps the `size_t index` argument to the right array. This wrapper class does need the size of every array though to be able to correctly map the index.

An example pseudocode operator[] would be:

```
int& JointDatabase::operator[](size_t index) {
    // database is an iDatabase
    iSection *cur = database.First_Section;

    while (cur != database.Last_Section && index >= cur->Section_Count) {
        index -= cur->Section_Count;
        cur = cur->Next;
    }

    return cur->Section_Arr[index];
}
```

Then use this wrapper class as you would use a normal container in your Quicksort algorith.

Comment: This sounds like the correct approach, however, I am not to sure how to do it.  Is it possible you could post an example?

Comment: How would you write this operator in constant time if the arrays had variable (unequal) sizes?

Comment: @Mark B: Given the memory constraints I think O(1) is a bit optimistic don't you? @Steve: Some example code is given. The example code has worst-case complexity O(n) where n is the amount of arrays.

Comment: @nightcracker I was simply observing that if the function isn't constant time, then the sort itself starts approaching polynomial time and for a large number of elements as the OP has, may take longer than desired. Most likely this is a solid performing solution and easy to understand.

Comment: You might want to cache the cumulative start indices of later sections rather than walking the list every time. But I can't believe making this look-up for every element read and write is going to be more efficient than coding some logic into the sort code, or using a different sort strategy.

Comment: @Rup: Yeah, but that would be complicating the answer. This is the essential way for my approach, and of course further optimizations can be made. But I would first write this and profile to see where I should optimize. Also, do not underestimate the compiler's optimizer.

Comment: @nightcracker: the optimizer of the compiler manages micro-optimizations well, but not algorithmic issues. Your code, as it is, does not provide a quick sort. Your `operator[]` has `O(M)` complexity where M is the number of buckets, and thus you'll have something close to `O(M N log N)` in complexity. That said, it may be overkill to try and optimizes it yet.

Comment: +1 - some optimize ideas: if the start index for a sub-array can be kept in the `JointDatabase` instead of the element count, a `lower_bounds` search can be done instead of linear. If you can afford a full index of sub-arrays you can get O(1) time again, with the overhead of the space for the index and one pass though the sub-array database to build the index.  Of course, the size of that index might not be acceptable (if your array elements are small - like ints - then the size of the index will be about the same as simply copying the sub-arrays into a large single array).

Comment: And if the sub-arrays can be forced to be same size (except maybe first and last), then you can find the sub-array using simple arithmetic in constant time (and you've reinvented deques). However, the OP has indicated that the sub-arrays will have arbitrary size.

Comment: @nightcracker: If you can wrap it and create an `operator []` for it, you can also create iterators that operate on the entire range. Then you could use `std::sort` and all the other standard algorithms on the data.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: Sadly, no. `std::sort` needs a `RandomAccessIterator`, which is an iterator that supports `++`, but also `--`. Since the linked list in question here is not doubly linked but just singly (or w/e it's called) this is impossible (or at least not efficient/logical).

Comment: @nightcracker: You are right, I missed that part. It would been such an elegant solution demonstrating the power of the iterator concept.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make sure that `Array1, Array2, and Array3` are declared one after another and in continuous memory layout, then you can give the `Array1` (the first one) in the `sort()` and give the combined size of all the arrays.

To check the continuous alignment you can use following trick.

```
template<size_t SIZE1, size_t SIZE2, size_t SIZE3>
bool Check(int (&a1)[SIZE1], int (&a2)[SIZE2], int (&a3)[SIZE3])
{
  return (&a3[SIZE3 - 1] - &a1[0]) == (SIZE1 + SIZE2 + SIZE3);
}
```

Usage,

```
bool aligned = Check(Array1, Array2, Array3);
```

This is an example for 3 arrays, you can make it according to your need. And you can pass Array1,2,3 or Array3,2,1 depending on your machine.

Comment: This wont always be the case.

Comment: @Steve, agreed. My answer is if you want to take a chance since your arrays are very huge.

Comment: The arrays are to large to put them in continuous memory layout. I dont think this approach will work.

Comment: ok ... by the way have you checked declaring them one after another ? And also using above function to check if they are aligned. This is just a suggestion, if you have time :)

Answer (score -1):

Tested only in my brain:

```
struct ArrayWrapper {
    int** arrays;
    int* running_sums;
    ArrayWrapper(int **arrays, int *arrays_length, int N) {
        running_sums = new int*[N+1];
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            running_sums[i+1] = sum;
            sum += arrays_length[i];
        }
    }
    int& operator[] (int index) {
        int array_start = binary search `running_sum` for the closest number to `index` (round down)
        return arrays[array_start][index - running_sums[array_start]]
    }
}
```

so if you have something like:

```
array1 = {...} 
array2 = {...}
...
arrayN = {...}

arrays = {array1, array2, ..., arrayN}
arrays_length = {array1_length, array2_length, ..., arrayN_length}

ArrayWrapper wrapper = new ArrayWrapper(arrays, arrays_length, N);
// wrapper then can be treated like normal array:
wrapper[10] = x;
x = wrapper[10];
```

Comment: The OP wants an in-place sort with no new allocations I believe.

Comment: -1, the asker specifically said linked list, which changes the situation dramatically.